# MySQL INNER JOIN with multiple values in a column

Tags: php, mysql

Does anyone knows how to do a mysql inner join with multiple values from a table in a column, I mean:

t_1:
       **`id_t1  |   name`**
                  `001 |   name_value`

t_2:
       **`id_t2  |   value`**
                  `020 |   value1`
           `030 |   value2`
           `040 |   value3`
           `050 |   value4`

t1_t2:
       **`id_t1  |   id_t2`**
                     `001 |   020`
              `001 |   030`
              `001 |   050`

Then, a query that return me for example, something like this:

**`id_t1  |   name`**           **`| values_t_2`**
    `001  |   name_value | value1, value2, value4`

If anyone can tell me a way to do this, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
    t1.id_t1,
    t1.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t2.value SEPARATOR ', ') AS values_t_2
FROM
    t_1 t1
    INNER JOIN t1_t2 t1t2 ON (t1.id_t1 = t1t2.id_t1)
    INNER JOIN t_2 t2 ON (t1t2.id_t2 = t2.id_t2)
GROUP BY
    t1.id_t1
```

Comment: @Sebas There is no standard SQL way to do this. Each SQL server implements its own mechanism.

Comment: this is correct, as of the group_concat thing. But I was refering to the GROUP BY part.

Comment: Because `t1.name` isn't wrapped in an aggregate function and therefore wouldn't work on most SQL servers?